# MongoDB check exists in array

Tags: mongodb

collection 'books':

```
array (
  '_id' => new MongoId("4e242b0ea5bb1bb00b000000"),
  'book' => 
  array (
    '0' => 1,
    '1' => 2,
    '2' => 3,
    '3' => 14,
    '4' => 15,
  ),
  'book_count' => 5,
  'user_name' => 'john',
)
```

How can I check where 'some book' in an array 'book'?

is this only way to check ?

```
db.books.count({user_name:'john', book:1})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, although the following would be faster

```
db.books.find({user_name:'john', book:1}).limit(1) != null
```